# I am using pymongo, and in the same script insert_one is working but delete_one is not working to delete a document in MongoDB

Tags: pymongo

I am using pymongo to connect with MongoDB. When I use the insert_one() method to insert a document, it is happening but when, all things same, I'm using delete_one() method, then no deletion is happening.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
democlient = MongoClient()
myclient = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mydb = myclient["testdb"]
mycoll = mydb["videos"]

myquery= {"id" :"23030784"}

mydoc=mycoll.delete_one(myquery) # not working , no deletion is happening 
mydoc=mycoll.insert_one(myquery) # is working , insertion is happening
```

Comment: What is `mycoll.count_documents(myquery)` before and after `delete_one`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs turns out there was some issue with the type. thanks